# Tesla Coil stops sparking until restart

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-fields

I have a tesla coil with NT-1530-OUT Transformer, 23 turns (max) primary, 1m secondary(~1600turns), with MMC and rotary sparkgap.

Gets 50cm sparks but try to tune the tesla coil by shifting top load, change turns at primary and adjust rotary spark gap.

But the big problem is that it always shuts of after some sparks and then you have to turn off and on the power again to make it work.

Anyone knows what the problem could be?

Would be realy happy to just get some hints or any help at all.

Thanks
Henrik

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 0):

Without more detailed data, further experimentation, I cannot provide a definite answer.

But with regards to your supply transformer that feeds the primary - could it possibly be a GFI protected transformer? Many of the later date neon light transformers (Franceformer for example) built GFI protectors into the transformers for safety. Using these transformers to drive a Tesla load can cause the GFI to trip.